# asp:Button having position:fixed/absolute is not clickable on firefox nor google chrome

Tags: asp.net, css, css-position

I am writing code in `ASP.NET`.

I have a button that is clickable on IE but not on FF nor Google Chrome.

I've discovered that the reason lays on the fact that its `position: absoulute` **OR** `position:fixed`
Here's the code:

```
<div style="padding-top:50px";>
            <div id="divInfoBox" runat="server" style="padding-top:5px; height:250px;"> 
                <div style="position:fixed; padding-left:-5px; ">
                    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="attachmentImageButton" ID="btnAttachment" runat="server" Visible="false"
                        ImageUrl="~/Style/images/attachment.png" onclick="btnAttachment_Click" />
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to make it be clickable on all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the first two `div` elements are on top of the `ImageButton` and therefore it is not clickable.
I have no clue why is that (be glad to find out the exact reason). All I know is that the solution is adding the following:

```
z-index:5
```

And that should do the trick.

Good luck

p.s.: if 5 isn't enough, try adding higher value.

Comment: i guess it's more like the fact, that asp elements are usually z-indexed- lower than their parents by default, even more, normally there is another container-layer placed "above" each element.

Comment: Yes, it came to me later on - what you said :)